# How to access a shared folder from Windows Cluster IP

Tags: windows, clustering, network

This is a very strange question, but I am trying to access a Windows file share from a SQL server cluster IP, that resides on that server. In the past and on other servers I have, I get connected to the share on the primary node. I just stood up a 2012R2 cluster and when I try to access the cluster IP I cannot get to any shares. It takes me to an empty share and does not let me navigate out of the share. Has anyone experienced this? Is there any way to resolve this? Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The problem was we mounted and unmounted the drives initially and that share is only created once automatically. You have to create it manually after the fact.